# Select all groups that contain all specified values in a certain column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

Say I have the following table:

| CaseRef | NotificationReason | NotificationDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | SCHEDULED | 2022-01-01 |
| 234 | SCHEDULED | 2022-01-02 |
| 312 | SCHEDULED | 2022-01-01 |
| 123 | RESCHEDULED | 2022-01-02 |
| 123 | DECIDED | 2022-01-03 |
| 234 | DECIDED | 2022-01-02 |

If I want to return only rows that have a `CaseRef` that has both a `SCHEDULED` and a `DECIDED` value in `NotificationReason`.

| CaseRef | NotificationReason | NotificationDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 234 | SCHEDULED | 2022-01-02 |
| 234 | DECIDED | 2022-01-02 |
| 123 | SCHEDULED | 2022-01-01 |
| 123 | RESCHEDULED | 2022-01-02 |
| 123 | DECIDED | 2022-01-03 |

I wrote the below which works fine and only excludes the one row, but I was wondering if this is the most efficient way of constructing such a query?

```
SELECT * 
FROM @Notifications
WHERE CaseRef IN (SELECT CaseRef FROM @Notifications
                  WHERE NotificationReason = 'SCHEDULED')
  AND CaseRef IN (SELECT CaseRef FROM @Notifications
                  WHERE NotificationReason = 'DECIDED')
ORDER BY CaseRef DESC
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yes this should be good and reasonably fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be reasonably fast for checking two statuses. But in case you want to check many statuses an alternate would be:

```
select *
from t
where caseref in (
    select caseref
    from t
    where notificationreason in ('SCHEDULED', 'DECIDED')
    group by caseref
    having count(distinct notificationreason) = 2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is OK but returns and additional row with NotificationReason RESCHEDULED so it should be:

```
select * FROM Notifications
where CaseRef in (select CaseRef from Notifications
where NotificationReason = 'SCHEDULED')
AND CaseRef in (select CaseRef from Notifications
where NotificationReason = 'DECIDED')
and NotificationReason<>'RESCHEDULED'
order by CaseRef desc
```

fiddler http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2bf412/17
And if you want to know the efficiency of a query check the execution plan

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the tip regarding sqlfiddle. I have been using that but didn't realise you could use it to measure query efficiency. I've had a look. That is really cool. Thanks so much. As for the query result, no thats fine, I wasn't wanting to return all the notifications for cases that had both the scheduled and decided, so including other notifications.

Comment: Although for my original query and the query provided by Salman A, the execution times vary every time I run it. The cost total always comes out as 98% just on different steps or components, so not sure how to evaluate the performance of these 2 queries. Would it become more obvious with a large table - as in more data?

Comment: It's evaluated step by step, every step of a query execution has a weight (the execution plan of a query is available primarily on every DBMS of course), operation having the biggest cost in this case is sorting (order).